# How to configure html templates in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, smarty, laravel-5.6

Hello i am  using Laravel framework. My client wants to implement the drag and drop of newsletter email builder where user can drag and drop the elements for that i will use some jquery plugins. Now i want suggestions from you guys how can i save Html in **database or blade files**?

if Database what would be the structure of database tables ??

if in blade files where i can save the blade files in public folder or view folder... if in public folder should i use (.html) extensions.

I have lot of other doubts.. if i have save Html content in database my website execution will be slow? Fothat i have read the Smarty Template engine  ... so how can i implement smarty in laravel.

Can anyone guide me or send some references it will really helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `blade` in laravel since you get good features that a templating engine should have.

---

Coming to the question of saving html in database or in blade files.

If there can be a similarity in layout of your newsletters, you can save the layout in blade files and just save the corresponding varying data in database.

But if there is a great changes in layouts (which I'm guessing there will be because people will be using drag and drop plugins as you mentioned), then it is really hard to output all the newsletters using one blade layout file. In this case you will have to save the html in database, and yes this can slow down the working of your website if you use an inefficient way to save the html.

Answer (score -1):

If you're new, please check the documentation first.

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/)

There you will find answers to most of your questions.

Comment: plz dont send laravel documentation i know the basics. Please answer to my question that i have asked. plz read my question properly